# easy slider overflow problem on first load (again same problem)

Tags: jquery, css, overflow, easyslider

I am having a strange problem, i am using easy slider 1.5 for slides. Everything works fine but when i load the page for the first time, right side overflows, then after refreshing the page once, everything goes to fine.........

here is the link for the main page [link text](http://www.gulzarchildcare.com)

Okay here is my CSS part of the code, i think that i dont know much about positioning so there must be some problem in that may be my sliderwrap.

**You can check the problem in Firefox 3.6 and chrome latest version.** In opera it doesn't happen at all. **Problem in google Chrome is more severe**

**There is one more thing i have noticed in firebug that when the website loades for the first time, the slider id width is shown to 1079px and height to 312px and when i refreshes the browser firefox and chrome (not opera), the width and height again go to actual and firebug shows me 901 and 303 pixels....**

Comment: is the javascript loading before the css file?

Comment: yes javascript is loading before css

Comment: okay superunited solved my problem, just loading the CSS file before your script execution was causing this problem of miscalculation of heights and widths.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to fix your css... if what you've posted is what you have, there's repeated attributions, but most importantly, you have syntax errors...

**missing class or id identifier:**

> nextBtn{left:1021px}
>
> prevBtn a,

Regarding your HTML, your post don't contain all of that slider's elements, but seems to be ok! The same for the Javascript Part!

Comment: You might be right, but why does my website loads accurately when i open the page from local disk, but when i go online with the same browser the over flow occurs on the first load......you can see it online by going to this site
http://www.gulzarchildcare.com

Comment: #sliderwrap{background-color:#00314e;
clear:left;
color:#f2f2f2;
}
#slider ul{list-style:none;margin:0;padding:0px;}
#slider li{width:901px;height:303px;overflow:hidden;}
#nextBtn{display:block;width:36px;height:36px;position:absolute;left:1025px;top:250px;z-index:1000;}
#prevBtn{display:block;width:36px;height:36px;position:absolute;left:70px;top:250px;z-index:1000;}
#prevBtn a{display:block;width:36px;height:36px;background:url(images/prebtn.png) no-repeat 0 0}
#nextBtn a{display:block;width:36px;height:36px;background:url(images/nextbtn.png) no-repeat 0 0}

Comment: okay the problem seems to be solved with applying local jquery.js file on host server. First i was fetching google latest jquery file with script. I have seen some articles on firefox bugs and there was some information to call jquery.js locally.........
And your suggestion was good to make code clearn, but the author of easyslider 1.7 have used very strange CSS codes........
Thanks for the help

Comment: No problem, glad to help :) Mark the answer as the correct one and close this topic! Good Luck!

Comment: it is not working again, particularly it is disastrous in Google Chrome latest version